# Strange bug with divs at same height overlapped with different z-index and with parent overflow hidden: border-bottom always is visible?

Tags: html, css, debugging, safari

I created a `speedometer` that works very well and is to light (with CSS3,html and js code). 
But i noticed a strange bug with iphone....

This is the CODE:

```js
$('#first').addClass('first-start');



//SECOND BAR
$('#second').addClass('second-start');

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#second').addClass('second-pause');
}, 400);
```

```css
#page {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 4;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#box-first,
#box-second {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#first,
#second {
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#n1,
#n2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  z-Index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@keyframes first {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  33% {
    background-color: yellow;
    transform: rotate(240deg);
  }
  66% {
    background-color: orange;
    transform: rotate(300deg);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes second {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  33% {
    background-color: yellow;
    transform: rotate(240deg);
  }
  66% {
    background-color: orange;
    transform: rotate(300deg);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.first-start,
.second-start {
  animation: first 2s linear forwards;
}
.first-pause,
.second-pause {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div id="box-first">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="n1">1500</div>
  </div>
  <div id="box-second">
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="n2">270</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With iphone, so with `safari`, under (at the bottom side) div `#n1` (the black div where there's number **1500**) is visible a small white border or sometimes red (like `#first`).
And this is impossible because the container has `overflow: hidden`, all divs have different z-Index and the **absolute** position of #n1 is correct.

How is possibile ?

Thanks and sorry for my english

This is the jsfiddle: This is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k85t9zgq/33/

This is a bug's screenshot:
[image]

**THIS IS NEW "BUG"** adding `box-sizing:border-box`

[image]

it seems to me that adding this new property not work the `overflow:hidden` property. 
Is possible?

Comment: Can you please share your screenshot?.

Comment: @jaydeeppatel i edited my question adding screenshot

Comment: have you tried setting box-first height to 99px ?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test this, but I am pretty sure it's related to the fact that background use `background-clip` border-box by default and this is somehow a rendring issue. A potential fix is to make the background far from the border by adding a small padding and adjusting `background-clip`

```js
$('#first').addClass('first-start');



//SECOND BAR
$('#second').addClass('second-start');

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#second').addClass('second-pause');
}, 400);
```

```css
#page {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 4;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#box-first,
#box-second {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  /* Changes*/
  background: linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) content-box;
  padding:1px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  /**/
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#first,
#second {
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#n1,
#n2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  z-Index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@keyframes first {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  33% {
    background-color: yellow;
    transform: rotate(240deg);
  }
  66% {
    background-color: orange;
    transform: rotate(300deg);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes second {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  33% {
    background-color: yellow;
    transform: rotate(240deg);
  }
  66% {
    background-color: orange;
    transform: rotate(300deg);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.first-start,
.second-start {
  animation: first 2s linear forwards;
}
.first-pause,
.second-pause {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div id="box-first">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="n1">1500</div>
  </div>
  <div id="box-second">
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="n2">270</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Temani :) now i’m not at home and i can’t to try your suggest. Anyway this speedometer give me a lot of problems. One of this is about setTimeout and how pause the animation excatly after 1 second. I hope you can help me... maybe suggesting something. Here the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213872/how-stop-keyframe-animation-exactly-after-1-second-without-to-use-settimeout

Comment: I hope in your help :D

Comment: The problem, with iphone (now i test only on iphone and not yet with android) seems that box-sizing "delete" overflow:hidden property. The bug of questions is solve but there's this other bug...

Comment: @Borja can you share a screenshot of the new bug?

Comment: @Borja in this case remove box-sizing:border-box and remove the padding for width/height ... so remove 2px from the width and the height, you should have the same output. I updated my answer

Comment: Pretty sure this is just the classic rounding error that you can't do much about except hack in some very precise (but imprecise-looking) fractions.

Comment: @BoltClock yes the first one seems a common issue but the second one is strange ... probably background clip is not well supported in some iOS version

Comment: nothing... with new your edit return the first bug.... maybe is impossible to solve :8

Comment: @Borja I think the issue is with background-clip ... can you try this: https://jsfiddle.net/cpde5asq/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's your border-radius property on `#first` and `#second` - Play around with the values on it and you will totally see what I mean.

Change this:

```
#first,
#second {
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0; /* ← CHANGE THIS */
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 200px; /* ← CHANGE THIS TOO */
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

to:

```
#first,
#second {
  border-radius: 0; /* ← THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT */
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 100%; /* ← THIS IS ALSO WHAT YOU WANT */
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

That faint white/gray line around your speedometer is no longer present.

Cheers and Happy coding :)

Comment: nothing...the bug is present. I tried your code, or adding grey border-bottom to div with inside the number. Nothing...