# How stop keyframe Animation exactly after 1 second without to use setTimeout ? - Problem events on queue

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, settimeout

I think this will be a problem really difficult to solve...

I created a speedometer that shows number of earthquakes occured in my city.
I want to animate this speedometer in two way:
`background-color` (green when there aren't quakes and red when there are **3000** quakes) and width of this colored div (the div where i animate background-color).
So the width will be **0** when there aren't quakes and will be 100% when there are 3000 quakes.

The animation is 2 seconds, so for example if i have **1500** quakes:
Add the class for animate speedometer

```
  $('#first').addClass('first-start');
```

And using `setTimeout` i add a class to stop the animation after 1 second

```
 setTimeout(function() {
   $('#first').addClass('first-pause');
 }, 1000);
```

This code almost always works great.

Now i add a snippet:

```js
$('#first').addClass('first-start');

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#first').addClass('first-pause');
}, 1000);
```

```css
#page {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 4;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#box-first{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#first{
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#n1{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  z-Index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes first {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  33% {
    background-color: yellow;
    transform: rotate(240deg);
  }
  66% {
    background-color: orange;
    transform: rotate(300deg);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}



.first-start {
  animation: first 2s linear;
}

.first-pause {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div id="box-first">
    <div id="first">

    </div>
    <div id="n1">
      1500
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hoymds97/

The problem is that i use this code in a big file (4000 lines) with a lot of events and in the same function there are 8 speedometers.
I noticed that sometimes (when there are more events) `setTimeout`  not start immediately after added class for animate speedometer.

As a result, the animation will stop after ...
In our case, for example, it is as if it blocked after 1700 milliseconds and not 1000 seconds. Sometimes it stops even after 2 seconds.

I think the problem is the many events in the `queue`.

So how can i solve this problem ?

Is possible to solve using always `setTimeout` or without it?

I hope you can help me and sorry for my english.

Comment: I think we should try another method for this, will think about it ;)

Comment: Have you thought about using the reqeustAnimationFrame method on the window? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete new idea that relies on transition instead of animation and where you can easily adjust the state without synchronization issue.

The main trick is to use a gradient for the background coloration and adjust its position in order to have the needed color.

Here is a simple code to illustrate the coloration:

```css
.box {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, yellow, orange, red);
  background-size: 2000% 100%;
  transition:1s;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  height: 200px;
}

.box:hover {
  background-position: 100% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

As you can see, I defined a gradient with the 4 colors and we simply need to adjust the `background-size` in order to have the coloration (`0%` for green and `100%` for red). This won't be exactly the same visually because we will not have a solid color like with animation and for this reason I made the `background-size` big enough to create the illusion of a solid color.

Now, we simply need to find the values of the `background-position` and the `degree` which is pretty easy. The `backround-position` is a value between `0%` and `100%` and the degree is a value between `180deg` and `360deg`. For the state `50%` we will logically use `50%` for the background-position and `270deg` for the transformation and for an `x%` state we will use respectively `x%` and `x%*(360deg - 180deg) + 180deg = x%*180deg + 180deg = 180deg(x% + 1)`

Here is an example with `50%` (hover to see)

```css
#page {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 4;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#box-first{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#first{
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, yellow, orange, red);
  background-size: 2000% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:0% 0%;
  transition:1s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#box-first:hover #first{
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  background-position:50% 0%;
}

#n1{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  z-Index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="box-first">
    <div id="first">

    </div>
    <div id="n1">
      1500
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

In order to make this dynamic, we need to adjust the values using JS and the transition will do the job. For this we can define a `data-attribute` for the state that we convert to the needed value.

Here is an example where I also simplified the html and used pseudo element and CSS variables

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.box').each(function() {
    var d = $(this).data('state');
    $(this).attr("style", "--s:" + d);
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, yellow, orange, red);
  background-size: 2000% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: calc(var(--s, 0) * 1%) 0%;
  transition:2s linear;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(calc((var(--s, 0)/100 + 1)*180deg));
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.box:after {
  content: attr(data-number);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto auto 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  z-Index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-number="1500" data-state="50"></div>

<div class="box" data-number="1000" data-state="20"></div>

<div class="box" data-number="3000" data-state="80"></div>

<div class="box" data-number="6000" data-state="100"></div>
```

You may notice that all will have the same duration since the transition is the same for all. In case you want a different duration and keep the same speed, simply use the CSS variable within the transition also.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.box').each(function() {
    var d = $(this).data('state');
    $(this).attr("style", "--s:" + d);
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, yellow, orange, red);
  background-size: 2000% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: calc(var(--s, 0) * 1%) 0%;
  transition: calc(2s * var(--s, 0)/100) linear;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(calc((var(--s, 0)/100 + 1)*180deg));
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.box:after {
  content: attr(data-number);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto auto 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 0 0;
  z-Index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-number="1500" data-state="50"></div>

<div class="box" data-number="1000" data-state="20"></div>

<div class="box" data-number="3000" data-state="80"></div>

<div class="box" data-number="6000" data-state="100"></div>
```

Comment: I agree and have seen much improvement using CSS transitions (a.k.a. animations) than using JavaScript. Especially on busy computers. I think that browsers somehow give priority to their CSS timers.

Comment: @Temani friday when i return at home i will try your code... but i’m sure is a great code ;) thanks a lot!

Comment: @temani last night I had another idea ... what do you think if we add the class of animation (the keyframe) that is 3.5 seconds in total and immediately after i add a setInterval (to be executed for example every 10 milliseconds) that intercepts the angle of rotation of the div that must be animated. if the angle corresponds to a certain value, setInterval end and add the pause to the animation. Do you think it could have the same problem as the initial code (the one with the setTimeout)?

Comment: @Borja but what is the difference with what you are doing actually? it's the same think, you add a class for the animation then a settimeout to pause it

Comment: Before i added the class and pause the animation after 1 second. But setTimeout, cause more events, started after (for example) after 0.5 second and stop it after 1.5 second. The setInterval every 10 millisecond works well. Sure if the delay is big this new strange idea don’t work good for speedometers with “low angle” (because i should to stop them after few milliseconds). Sorry for this idea... when i return at home the first thing i will do is to try your code. Ah... do you think that your code will work also with principal browser? Is supported? Thanks a lot for all!

Comment: @Borja yes my code is supported for all moderne browser ... there is only the use of CSS variable that can create issue for old borwser like IE, but you can easily change the code without it .. I simply try to make a simplified version of code, but we can add more code and make it more supported for old browser